# Can I compile a Scala file with a different name than the class?

Tags: scala

Can I compile a Scala file with a different name than the class?

```
   object HelloWorld {
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("Hello, world!")
      }
    }
```

Hello.scala

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried? Then you would notice that, yes, you can. Indeed you can place multiple classes in the same file, and therefore there is no restriction as to how the file must be called.

Comment: I am also trying the same thing. I tried to compile a scala class having different class name and file name. Could you please add more details here which can help new scala starters.